# HTML error 401 unauthorized when using Authorize Attribute in .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, attributes, authorize

Iam using authorize to lock the controller after a user signs in. Users are saved in EF with no use of roles or something like that. I read the documentation of authorize and it seems like I have to specify users or roles that could have access to the locked controller;

Here i have the Account controller;

```
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

When a user logs in, the user should be redirected to this action which is locked with the attribute [Authorize], but unfortunately i am getting this error "Html error 401 unauthorized".
My question is: how to give access to all users that are registered in EF DB to get redirected to the next page and skip this error??

Comment: Your question doesn't really make sense. If they are logged in, then the `Authorize` attribute will not reject them.

Comment: You don't have to specify roles. If you use just Authorize attribute, it blocks anyone not authenticated.

Comment: @Eric Hotinger Bro I understand that, my problem is that I am getting http error 401 unauthorized even if user name and password are true.. So Iam missing something to allow users that are saved in database have access to next page after login

Answer (score 3):

Following are the solution:

1- I had to change the Web.config file and add in the  following:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Home/Login" timeout="2880"  />
</authentication>
```

and then decorate the controller with [Authorize]

2- I had to clear cookies from browser (Google Chrome) to make it work otherwise Iam still be able to get access to account controller. Cleaning cookies will delete the old one and start a new one.

Answer (score 2):

Adding the `Authorize` attribute with no parameters will grant access to *any* user who is logged in:

```
[Authorize]
public class PrivateAreaController
{
    //
}
```

Or on an individual action:

```
public class MostlyPublicController
{
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult GetPrivateStuff()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Comment: Bro I understand that, my problem is that I am getting http error 401 unauthorized even if user name and password are true..